# How we can show Membership plan using AEC Component in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I want to handle different kind of member depend on their subscription.For that purpose i am using AEC Component.There will be different plan available, A user can subsribe any of the plan.
please tell me detail how i can do it..

Thanks in advance..

Pramod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Payplans](http://www.jpayplans.com) for subscription. This extension is easy to configure. And they provides video tutorials, which make it too easy to configure it.